# Why can i change the value of a constant (const char * ) trough a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

The title says it all. How am I able to change the value of a constant?
Also is that the same as when you change the value of an element at index X of a constant array?

```
    #include<iostream>
    int main(){
        const char* y = "original";
        auto *p = &y;
        *p = "modified";
        std::cout<<y<<"\n";
        //outputs modified
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're changing what `y` points to.

Comment: Now try `y[0] = 'x';`.

Comment: hmmm i get that, but then at the end of the day does a constant string/char make sense anymore ?

Comment: Yes it does but there is a difference btw constant pointer and pointer to const data. Also there is difference btw modifying pointer (make it point to different location) and modifying data it points to.

Comment: Yes it makes sense. You can't change a literal but that's not what your code does, and `y` is not a constant...

Comment: I that what you wanted? ```char * const y = "original";``` gives ```error: assignment of read-only location ‘* p’```

Comment: ok i kind of got it with @songyuanyao's explanation now, thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `y` is a **non-const** pointer (to `const`). You're not modifying the `const` part, i.e. the `const char` pointed by `y`, but `y` itself; this is valid. BTW modifying `y` through the pointer `p` is just same as

```
const char* y = "original";
y = "modified";  // this is well-formed
```

On the other hand,

```
*y = 'm';  // this is ill-formed
```

If you make `y` `const`, then you might get the diagnostic you expected.

```
const char* const y = "original";
y = "modified";  // ill-formed
*y = 'm';        // ill-formed
```